# Please delete [tag:tweaking]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[tweaking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tweaking) has been recently created - please burninate it before it picks up too many uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shall trouble you no more. Until someone else makes it again.

Comment: Isn't there a way to prevent future creation?  Or is that dev only?

Comment: @Holo, Only devs can add it and it's not worth troubling them unless the tag is likely to come up again (like VMWare et alii).